# My shell implementation overwriting when I don't want it to

Tags: c, linux, shell, stdout

I currently have a rudimentary implementation of Bash written in C. However, I'm getting issues when I try to redirect the standard output twice. Here is the relevant code:

Reading in each command:

```
for ( ; ; ) {
        printf ("(%d)$ ", nCmd);                // Prompt for command
        fflush (stdout);
        if ((line = getLine (stdin)) == NULL)   // Read line
            break;                              //   Break on end of file

        list = lex (line);
        free (line);
        if (list == NULL) {
            continue;
        } else if (getenv ("DUMP_LIST")) {      // Dump token list only if
            dumpList (list);                    //   environment variable set
            printf ("\n");
        }

        cmd = parse (list);                     // Parsed command?
        freeList (list);
        if (cmd == NULL) {
            continue;
        } else if (getenv ("DUMP_TREE")) {      // Dump command tree only if
            dumpTree (cmd, 0);                  //   environment variable set
            printf ("\n");
        }

        process (cmd);                          // Execute command
        freeCMD (cmd);                          // Free associated storage
        nCmd++;                                 // Adjust prompt
    }
```

The part of the shell we're my code is messing up:

```
if (cmdList->type==SIMPLE)
    {
        pid_t fork_result;
            fork_result = fork();
            if (fork_result < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Fork failure");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if (fork_result == 0) {
                if (cmdList->fromType==RED_IN)
                {
                    int fe = open(cmdList->fromFile, O_RDONLY, 0);
                    dup2(fe, 0);
                    close(fe);
                }
                if ((cmdList->toType==RED_OUT) || (cmdList->fromType==RED_APP))
                {
                    int fd = open(cmdList->toFile, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0666);
                    dup2(fd, 1);
                    close(fd);
                }
                execvp(cmdList->argv[0],cmdList->argv);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            else {
                int status;
                wait(&status);
            }

    }
```

This last snippet of code works exactly how I intend it to when I'm reading in just one simple command. However, the issue arises when I use the for loop to try to redirect stout twice. For example, I try to run:

```
cat Tests/star.wars > +Bash.tmp
cat +Bash.tmp

cat Tests/stk.txt   > +Bash.tmp
cat +Bash.tmp
```

The first command writes, say, "ABC" to Bash.tmp. However, when I run the second command, I expect it to return "DE". However, I'm getting "DEC" as the output. What is wrong?

Comment: You aren't using `O_TRUNC` in the `open` call?

Comment: Should I be? I heard that O_WRONLY should do the trick.

Comment: `O_WRONLY` is "write-only" permissions. `O_TRUNC` is what truncates the file on open.

Comment: The Bash shell is a large and complex code-base (with many features beyond those required by POSIX). I think it would be more correct to say that you're implementing a Unix or Bourne-compatible shell.

Comment: Your `getLine()` only takes one parameter, so it's not the POSIX `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);`. How does yours work?

Answer (score 0):

`O_WRONLY` is "write-only" permissions. `O_TRUNC` is what truncates the file on open.
                    – Etan Reisner